# perforce: how to propogate unsubmitted changes

Tags: perforce

I have made some changes in one perforce client, but haven't submitted them. I want to propagate these changes to another perforce client, without submitting the changes in the first client.

Is it possible? If yes how?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this from within Perforce itself.  You will need to perform a manual process:

1. sync and resolve any conflicts with the changes on Client A
2. sync Client B
3. check out target files on Client B
4. copy files from Client A to Client B

This process could be automated by using commands like `p4 changes` and `p4 describe` and OS tools to parse the output (like `for` in DOS), but this would be overkill in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

check out the new shelving feature in the perforce 9.2 release (currently available in beta)- you can cache your modified files on the server, without having to check them in as a versioned change.

http://blog.perforce.com/blog/?p=1872

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't work with git-p4, the answer to this question seems to refer to your use case as well: [git-p4 and pulling from other repos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620132/git-p4-and-pulling-from-other-repos/1622576#1622576)